# Draw icons on canvas in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, canvas, cytoscape.js

I am using `cytoscape.js`. I want to draw a small delete icon next to selected nodes, but I have no idea how to draw on the canvas using the [API](http://js.cytoscape.org/).

I guess I should listen for a select even

```
cy.on('select', '*', function (event) {
  const element = event.cyTarget;

  // draw icon on the canvas
})
```

The library has many [extensions](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/ui-extensions), so I know it is possible to draw on top of the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Following @maxkfranz's (Cytoscape dev) recommendations, I develop a lightweight Cytoscape.js extension called [cytoscape-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cytoscape-canvas) that creates a canvas over and/or under a graph. With it, creating that delete icon becomes super easy. I did something similar with a notification badge:

[image: Preview]

If you're interested, check out the [readme](https://github.com/classcraft/cytoscape.js-canvas)!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new canvas in your Cytoscape div -- putting it on top of the graph.  This is the same approach that the extensions use.

(You shouldn't modify the canvas(es) that belong to Cytoscape, as it would almost certainly create problems.)